# How many ways are there to build a tower of 5 cubes height, out of red, yellow, blue, and green cubes, such that:

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

> How many ways are there to build a tower of 5 cubes height, out of red, yellow, blue, and green cubes, such that at least one of each pair of adjacent cubes is green or blue?

Hey everyone. I first thought about solving this using a recursion relation but then realised it might be better to solve it using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

My attempt: Define $A_i$ - there is no blue/green cube among the pair of cubes: cube $i$ and cube $i+1$. $1\le i\le 4$

We are looking for $|\bigcap_{i=1}^4 \overline {A_i}|=|\overline {\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i}| $

$|\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i}| $= $4^5-4(2^2)+6(2^3)-4(2^4)+2^5$

where $4^5$ is the number of ways to build the tower without any restraints, etc. Is this correct, am I doing something wrong? Edit: Yes this is indeed not correct and yes I am indeed wrong :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the number $4(2^2)$ come from?

Comment: @Y.Forman $4C1$ times $2^2$- for each $A_i$ there are 2 choices available (either red or yellow) for each cube in places i, i+1. Is this not correct?

Comment: Have you checked the result? My instinct tells me that it might be incorrect ;) I mean, compare $4^5$ with your final result...

Comment: @NoyPerel See the first bullet point in my answer.

Comment: @57Jimmy Yeah, it makes no sense then. oops :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is good, but two things should be fixed:

- The number of ways to color cubes outside of $i,i+1$ is not considered. E.g., you claim there are $2^2$ ways to color cases where $i,i+1$ are not green/blue. There are $2$ choices for each of cubes $i,i+1$ but also four choices for each of the other three cubes, so there should be $2^24^3$ ways of coloring this case.
- There are two ways in which two pairs of cubes can be colored without green/blue: three consecutive cubes colored not green/blue (your $+6\dots$ term), and two separate pairs colored without green/blue. You don't account for the second type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I still end up with a result that doesn't make sense though so I guess I still haven't grasp the idea. I ended up with the expression $4^5-4(2^2 4^3)+6(2^3 4^2+2^4 4)-4(2^4 4)+2^5$

Comment: @NoyPerel There aren't $6$ ways to have two separate pairs, there are only $4$.

Comment: Thank you! So is it $4^5-4(2^2 4^3)+(6(2^3 4^2)+4(2^4 4))-4(2^4 4)+2^5$ then?

Comment: @NoyPerel You might also have to fix the three-pairs term, since three pairs can also occur (partially) separately

Comment: I give up... What is the final expression then, please? I think I am not getting the correct result..

Comment: @NoyPerel I may have misled you... of the 6 double pairs, there are 3 consecutive triples and 3 separate pairs.  Of the 4 triple pairs, there are 2 consecutive quadruples and 2 triple/double setups.  The answer should be $4^5 - 42^24^3 +(32^34^2+32^44)-(22^44+22^5)+2^5$

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach: Denote by $a_n$ the number of admissible towers of height $n$. Then we have the recursion
$$a_0=1, \quad a_1=4,\qquad a_n=2a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}\quad(n\geq2)\ .$$
(In order to build an admissible tower of height $n$ begin with a blue or a green cube, and erect on it an admissible tower of height $n-1$; or begin with a red or a yellow cube, top it by a blue or a green cube, and erect on them an admissible tower of height $n-2$.)

The recursion can be solved using the "Master Theorem". One obtains
$$a_n={5+3\sqrt{5}\over 10}\bigl(1+\sqrt{5}\bigr)^n +{5-3\sqrt{5}\over 10}\bigl(1-\sqrt{5}\bigr)^n\ .$$
In particular $a_5=416$.